# How do I access two hidden controls on Kontakt Player running Blüthner Model One (virtual piano)?

Tags: virtual, piano

Dear all interested parties,

I am trying to properly interface the Bluthner Model One virtual piano to my MIDI keyboard controller.  This virtual instrument works within Kontakt Player 5.  Presently, the velocity settings need adjusting. I did work on this years ago and came up with an instrument setting that wasn't too bad. Today, I have no idea how I achieved this.

Below is a screen shot of my old "instrument" and below it, a version of the instrument loaded from presets that allows a higher range of velocity (55 vs 45) [Bluthner Classical 45 vs 55.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCBGP.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCBGP.jpg).  Note that the latter has two less controls to the left than the top instrument has.  Without those two additional controls, I will not be able to achieve a proper response from my keyboard.  Also there is a defeat switch for these additional controls in the first instrument that is not present in the second.  I need to recreate these options in any additional versions of the instrument.

I have tried working with all of the tools I could find on the interface. I've spent hours searching the web for answers, but nothing.  There is an included script for velocity, but this is generic and is included in the multis rather than the instruments that I am dealing with.  I'm using a Mac, but that should not make a difference.

I realize this is a niche subject.  Any advice would be gratefully received!

Thank you,

sr

Answer (score 0):

I originally posted here because I thought I may have to write some scripting code for this.  Fortunately I was able to figure it out.  There were two DVDs included with the package I bought from a music store on special clearance.  The original disc ran on OS 10.4.11, or Windows XP.  Getting it to run properly on later systems is problematic.  Then, you have to update it with a second disk.  Due to problems on the second installer, *I never received the updated instrument files (.nki Kontakt files), only the original ones.*  On the one newer .nki file I somehow did get, I thought I had accidentally activated something to display the two extra controls.

On my Mac, I found the second installer will hang on the last item, which contains the updated nki files.  My solution was to run the installer again, whereupon I received the updated nki files.  And then you must be careful not to let the installer promptly erase them again!  I had this happen as well.

I can see why this piano did not get as much use as it should have.

The page I finally found that has the proper data is at http://www.proaudiovault.com/bdmo-installation.htm.  I never had this newer data as it is not included on either disk.  The perfect setup!

Well, I hope this saves some poor soul the trouble I had.